# Problem with JFace Application in design mode

Tags: java, eclipse, jface, windowbuilder

I installed Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers 2020-09 with WindowBuilder 1.9.4. Then I tried to create a test application: SWT/JFace Java Project with a JFace ApplicationWindow.

My problem is that I cannot drop anything on the window directly in design mode. It is possible to add widgets to the main container in the components tree. But they seem to be hidden behind the parent shell (I could see this from setting a background color for it and when I add them I can see their bounds, but then no longer). It is not possible to resize the application window in design mode either.

However, when I do "Test/Preview...", the widgets are there. And also when I run the program, as they should as they are in the code. In the latter case also the resizing works (not with "Test/Preview..."). The resizing seems to work at first, but then it snaps back to a minimal size where only the menu and toolbar fit in the window,

This is so with any such project. I first tried to import a program I had written in an older version of Eclipse. There I have tabs in a composite in the container. They seem to be hidden, too (and misplaced, also behind the toolbar). But when I run the program, everything is fine. I first thought I might have messed something up in the program, so parsing gets sidetracked. But that cannot be it as the problem already arises in the simple test program where I have just one widget and the default code.

I have tried quite a few things to get around this, eg. reinstalled the IDE, installed an older version, installed an older version of WindowsBuilder in case this is a bug in either. But to no avail. Has anyone experienced the same problem? Seems like there is a simple mistake on my part. Something I would have to change in the settings or maybe the program?

But I have no idea where to look. Could it have to do with the JRE (OpenJDK15U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_15_36)? Had to take that as the download from Oracle does not work for some reason. There is a warning that it is not exactly compatible. But then the program works fine, so it cannot be at such a basic level? Any ideas very much appreciated as I am totally stuck at this point.

There is no problem with designing eg. a JFace dialog. Everything works as expected, I can drop widgets, resize, etc.

Here is how it looks:
[image: Here is how it looks:]

Answer (score 0):

Brute force "workaround": I go back to Oxygen where things are working fine. But somewhat of a defeat because I am stuck with an old version, which is a deadend. IIRC already going to Photon posed insurmountable problems for me (certainly my fault as I am not that good at the nitty-gritty). Would still be very interested in an answer to my question. Urgency is now lower as I can at least keep working on my program and let my frustration die down after two days of futile attempts.

[Edit: I only tried the resizing in Oxygen 32-bit, that worked, but did not check whether the problem with dropping a widget on the application window was also there. Then I tried to get the 64-bit version to run, which I could not do. There is apparently a problem with Java > 8. Installation of Photon worked finally. However, while resizing is okay there, I get the same problem with dropping widgets and that they appear to be misplaced (upper left corner of the area seems to be behind the toolbar. The "workaround" unfortunately went nowhere. So I am again more interested in an answer than I thought.]

[Edit 2 as per Oct 12: Since I could not solve this problem, I decided to redo the GUI with a SWT Application window. That lacks some of the functionality of a JFace Application window (I especially miss the ease of Actions). So it seems like a step backwards, and it caused some extra effort. But then the upside is that I had to rethink a few things about the structure anyway, which means I was forced to do that sooner than later. But still would like to get also JFace Application windows to run. Pressure is no longer there, but out of interest what went wrong.]